# insert data from JSON into mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json

I have an JSON that I would like to insert into mysql database. My JSON is

```
{"users": { "bert":6.44, "earnie":0.25, "bigbird":34.45 }}
```

I have a table in mysql called "USERSAMOUNTS" with two coloumns.

The columns are called "USERNAME" and "AMOUNT".

I am trying to insert each name into USERNAME column and each amount into AMOUNT column in one query using a foreach loop and implode. The code I am using is as follows....

```
$array = json_decode($data, true);
$keys = array_keys($array);                          // get the value of keys
$rows = array();                                     // create a temporary storage for rows
foreach($keys as $key) 
{                                                    // loop through
    $value = $array[$key];                           // get corresponding value
    $rows[] = "('" . $key . "', '" . $value . "')";  // add a row to the temporary storage 
}
$values = implode(",", $rows);           // 'glue' your rows into a query                                    
$hostname = 'localhost';                 // write the rest of your query
$username = 'usersname';
$password = 'userspassword';
try 
{
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=my_database", $username, $password);
    echo 'Connected to database<br />'; // echo a message saying we have connected 
    $count = $dbh->exec("INSERT INTO USERAMOUNTS(USERNAME, AMOUNT) VALUES ($values)"); 
    echo $count;// echo the number of affected rows
    $dbh = null;// close the database connection
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

....my problem is when I run the code all I get is message
`Connected to database` to confirm database connection. No records are inserted and no error messages are shown. Can anyone here point out where I am going wrong and maybe give me a hint as to how to fix the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code:

```
$array = json_decode($data, true);
$rows = array();                                   
foreach($array['users'] as $key => $value)                         
    $rows[] = "('" . $key . "', '" . $value . "')"; 

$values = implode(",", $rows);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem at the beginning of your code:

```
$array = json_decode($data, true);
$keys = array_keys($array);                          // get the value of keys
$rows = array();                                     // create a temporary storage for rows
foreach($keys as $key) 
{                                                    // loop through
    $value = $array[$key];                           // get corresponding value
    $rows[] = "('" . $key . "', '" . $value . "')";  // add a row to the temporary storage 
}
```

`$array` is a multi-dimensional array with only one element with the key of `users`, so you are not looping over your data, but over the outer array. If you enable error display you will already see a warning: `PHP Notice: Array to string conversion` on the line of:

```
$rows[] = "('" . $key . "', '" . $value . "')";
```

You need to loop over the content of your `users` sub-array:

```
foreach ($array['users'] as $key => $value) {
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need brackets in insert

```
$count = $dbh->exec("INSERT INTO USERAMOUNTS(USERNAME, AMOUNT) VALUES " . $values);
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer - when I replace with your code i only have one record inserted USERNAME has users posted to it and AMOUNT is default 0.

Comment: what's the field type of [AMOUNT]?

Comment: the field type is decimal(16,8) also sorry I don't think i was clear - i don't have a username 'users' - that is at the start of the json object - but i don't need to store that.

Answer (score 0):

Initial problem is that your array is not $array, but $array["users"].

Do the following.
Replace all that

```
$keys = array_keys($array);                          // get the value of keys
$rows = array();                                     // create a temporary storage for rows
foreach($keys as $key) 
{                                                    // loop through
    $value = $array[$key];                           // get corresponding value
    $rows[] = "('" . $key . "', '" . $value . "')";  // add a row to the temporary storage 
}
$values = implode(",", $rows);           // 'glue' your rows into a query
```

with the following:

```
$values = Array();
foreach($array["users"] as $user=>$amount) {
    $values[] = "('" . $user. "', '" . $amount. "')";
}
```

Less code - same result.