# How to insert the jsonArray to MySQL in android client?

Tags: android

I have reference on [this site](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/267023/send-and-receive-json-between-android-and-php) to send data to `MySQL` but I don't know the function of this code `$json = file_get_contents('php://input');`

I have this `jsonArray` :

```
[{"id":"1","nilai":"1"},{"id":"2","nilai":"1"},{"id":"3","nilai":"1"},{"id":"4","nilai":"1"},{"id":"5","nilai":"1"}]
```

But again, I don't know how to send those `json` to database, and the tutorial in go*gle is so scrimpy for my issue. so I begging someone to help me.

***Question :***

- Is it possible to add the `jsonArray` to database in case the String inside `json` is looped?

That's mean is it possible to add/insert those `json` to database? how to do? and the final maybe like this :

```
|----|-------|
| ID | Nilai |
|----|-------|
| 1  |   1   |
| 2  |   1   |
| 3  |   1   |
|... |  ...  |
|====|=======|
```

Comment: I've looking for a piece of code like `json_decode(json)` but i don't have an idea to create a php script for that,

Comment: [take a look here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16684188/php-inserting-json-data-into-mysql-database-from-android) will you an idea how to do it

Comment: @PavneetSingh and again with this code `file_get_contents("php://input");`, that's `php://input` is a special character or?

Comment: you can easily google these things and read about it , pretty easy to find

Comment: @PavneetSingh so it's just like uploading a file to server and read that file then execute the query?

Comment: i already answered this question i invite you too see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41107092/tutorial-to-send-data-as-jsonarray-to-mysql-in-android-using-php/43932884#43932884

Answer (score 0):

Usually you do a HTTP POST with that JSON to a webserver, which will parse the data and it will insert to database ( MySQL). At the webserver will run a PHP code in most cases, but can be C#, Java. Usually you don't have access to MySql. Otherwise you have to build up a jdbc connection and use an SQL, not a JSON.

[Here](http://www.wikihow.com/Execute-HTTP-POST-Requests-in-Android) is an example hot to do a HTTP POST at Android.

[Here](http://www.kodingmadesimple.com/2014/12/how-to-insert-json-data-into-mysql-php.html) and  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21780864/insert-data-from-json-into-mysql-using-php) you will find piece of PHP code.

Comment: can you explain with code how to do for the _answer_, or maybe you should comment for that suggest

Comment: thanks for the example sir, but i don't know about `File_Get_Contents()` and how to insert my `json` into a file like (xyz.json)